# Prove that for infinitely many composite natural numbers n , $n|3^{n-1}-2^{n-1}$

Tags: number-theory

Prove that for infinitely many composite natural numbers n , $n|3^{n-1}-2^{n-1}$

If $n$ is prime it is obvious by fermat's little theorem.
But I think for $n=4k+1$ ,there might be infinitely such $n$ for which the result holds.

Comment: When $n=4k+1$, $3^{n-1}-2^{n-1} = 3^{4k} - 2^{4k} = (3^{2k} + 2^{2k})(3^k+2^k)(3^k-2^k)$.  But I don't know if that gets you anywhere.

Comment: All the composite solutions below 10000 are $[65,133,529,793,1105,1649,1729,2059,2321,2465,2701,2821,4187,5185,6305,6541,6601,6697,6817,7471,7613,8113,8911]$., including Ramanujan's taxicab number.

Comment: i think a good approach is to try to prove that if $n|3^{n-1}-2^{n-1}$ then $3^{n-1}-2^{n-1} | 3^{3^{n-1}-2^{n-1}-1}-2^{3^{n-1}-2^{n-1}-1}$